# Change parameters to fixed values in offset\fetch clause

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate with Progress OpenEdge 11.3 Update 2 ODBC Driver. The driver (or OpenEdge) does not allow parameters in offset\fetch clauses. The offset\fetch clause must contain fixed values. According to the documentation and this article:
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/2916

**Not allowed:**
select * from PUB.customer offset **?** rows fetch next **?** rows

Execption:
ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Syntax error in SQL statement at or about "? rows fetch next ? rows only " (10713)

**Allowed:**
select * from PUB.customer offset **10** rows fetch next **10** rows

How can I modify NHibernate's behaviour to use fixed values instead of parameters, when using Linq?

var customers = session.Query().Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();

Maybe someone can point me to the right direction. I have already downloaded the NHibernate sources and debugged them, but I could not find the right place to replace the parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

I set UseVariableLimits to false within my custom Nhibernate ODBC dialect. Furthermore, I installed the NHibernate 4.0.0.-Alpha2 nuget package.

This fixed the problem. Hope that NHibernate 4.0.0 will be stable and released soon.